# Set gray background color for read-only QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Right now a read-only plain text edit has a white coloring, which does not make it obvious that it's read-only. I need to make my read-only plain text edit to be "gray". However, by gray I mean the default system color corresponding to it, instead of a hard-coded RGB(127, 127, 127).

The reason I can't just disable the widget is that I want the user to be able to select and copy the text. This is possible with read-only edit boxes but not if they are disabled.

Example screenshot of what I have in mind:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very late response, but just looking for the same. Above solution works very nicely, but I guess the following code is more qt'isch:

```
// read-only PlainTextEdit with gray background
QColor mainWindowBgColor = palette().color(QPalette::Window);
// for the current widget
setStyleSheet(QString("QPlainTextEdit[readOnly=\"true\"] { background-color: %0 }").arg(mainWindowBgColor.name(QColor::HexRgb)));

// or application wide do:
qApp->setStyleSheet(QString("QPlainTextEdit[readOnly=\"true\"] { background-color: %0 }").arg(mainWindowBgColor.name(QColor::HexRgb)));
```

Advantage is that you need to do it only once, but gaining a consistent look and feel. *Please pay attention of using the complex selector in the square brackets.* Disadvantage is, but that's the same issue with the above code, that changing the OS design/profile will not have an effect until you re-execute the code (most probably doing a restart of your application).
- Its very sad that QtDesigner does not offer a simple way to do that - or I did not yet figure out how to do it.

And finally as application wide one-liner for all elements having a readOnly attribute set:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(QString("[readOnly=\"true\"] { background-color: %0 }").arg(qApp->palette().color(QPalette::Window).name(QColor::HexRgb)));
```

Comment: This is a little hard to understand for somebody who is new to Qt. What is `qApp`?

Comment: @robert It is a pointer to the global application instance.

Answer (score 2):

After some Googling and some experimenting, I found out how to do it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPalette readOnlyPalette = ui->plainTextEdit->palette();
    QColor mainWindowBgColor = palette().color(QPalette::Window);
    readOnlyPalette.setColor(QPalette::Base, mainWindowBgColor);
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPalette(readOnlyPalette);
}
```

Comment: This is nice and all, but the palette is set widget-wide disregarding its current state. For this to be an acceptable answer, you'd have to store two palettes and switch between them when the `readOnly` property is changed - which might not be that simple seeing how there's no signal for it. The stylesheet approach is simpler and results in achieving the desired behaviour out of the box.